# C# visual studio multiply 2 textbox

Tags: c#

I'm new with visual studio c#. I find no solution for next code.

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(textEdit16.Text);


textEdit17.Text= Convert.ToString(a);
```

Error:

> 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: Simply `a.ToString()`

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work either.

Comment: _”I already tried that and it doesn't work either”_ … ? … Tried what and why doesn’t it work, does it throw an error? The posted code does not make a lot of sense. The error appears to be complaining about the line… `int a = Convert.ToInt32(textEdit16.Text);` … which would indicate that whatever TEXT is in … `textEdit16.Text` … that it is not a valid `int` “number.” Since it unclear what you are trying to do, you could do something like… `textEdit17.Text = textEdit16.Text;` … and accomplish the same thing without “converting” anything. Can you elaborate what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use debugging to view the value of `textedit16`. Text and set the `textedit16`. Text property to enter only numbers